# Can not change custom view's frame size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode6, autolayout

I have a custom uiview. I used xib to layout the subviews and added constraints to autolayout them. Blow is it in IB.
[image]

[image]

Now I have some code which overriding the initWithFrame: method.
Here is the code.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {
    MyCustomView *view = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    [self addSubview:view];
}
return self;
```

}

And, in some other source, Im creating it using initWithFrame: method defined above and adding it to a UIScrollView. Im using constraints to let the scrollview's frame fit screen size. Code here.

```
CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
for (int index = 0;index < self.valueData.count;index ++) {
    MyCustomView *cellView = [[MyCustomView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CUSTOM_VIEW_HEIGHT * index, SCREEN_WIDTH, CUSTOM_VIEW_HEIGHT)];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:cellView];
    contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, cellView.frame);
}
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

What Im seeing in iPhone 5s simulator :

[image]

But in iPhone 6 simulator :

[image]

They are not taking the full width of screen although I's set the frame's width to SCREEN_WIDTH, which is defined :

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width)
```

How can I set these custom view's width to fit the screen width in multiple device ?

**ADDED :** 
Here is all the constraints of the UI contents in the custom view.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of all autolayout constraints (labels etc) ?

Comment: @JulianM Hi, I've added the screen shot of all the UI content in my custom view.

Comment: Try to change the frame in viewDidLayout or something like that, I think the IB overrides your frame so just set the frame after ib layout everything

Comment: @user3351949 Do you mean 'viewDidLoad' ? I think there is no super method called 'viewDidLayout'. And, since this is a UIView subclass, there is also no 'viewDidLoad' method.

Comment: @Sabbath No I don't mean viewDidLoad, then in your viewController class should be a delegate something like viewDidLayoutSubviews, try to setFrame of your view from there.(Sorry I am away from working environment, I just trying to help).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing Autolayout and setFrame is generally a bad idea which leads to a lot of suffering when you're trying to debug. Have you looked at what the auto generated constraints are yet with "Capture View Hierarchy"?

What you really want to do is not rely on generated constraints (especially since you can't rely on the view/window size before it's displayed). There's actually a few very important things you need to do:

1. Don't attach multiple views directly to a scrollview. You want *one*
   view attached to the scrollview, and everything else as a subview of
   that. I usually call it Content View.
2. Make sure your Content View is correctly attached to your scrollview before 
   adding additional content (no errors/warnings).
3. Insert your Asset Views with constraints. 0 to the right and left, and 0 to 
   the last view. Doesn't matter if you us constraintWithItem or
   constraintsWithVisualFormat.
4. Tie the bottom of the content view to the last inserted subview so it has a 
   defined height, remove or de-prioritize any other height constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think this is the best answer.

Comment: You're welcome - hope you got it working the way you wanted!

Answer (score 0):

Set a break point at

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = contentRect.size;
```

And you will see the size is wrong.

As you added constraints in xib, which override [super initWithFrame:] once addSubView called. That's why screen size doesn't effect.

Your constraints look right, try to make scrollView's contentSize as screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below method and call it after adding subview.

```
-(void)addBasicConstraintsOnSubView:(UIView *)subView onSuperView:(UIView *)superView
{
    [subView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|-%f-[subView]-0-|",subView.frame.origin.y] options: NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView)]];
    [superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"|-%f-[subView]-%f-|",subView.frame.origin.x,subView.frame.origin.x] options: NSLayoutFormatAlignmentMask metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(subView)]];
}
```